# Delete Multiple Object Properties Using Destructuring

Tags: ecmascript-6, destructuring, object-destructuring

I am trying to delete multiple computed properties from an object at once using destructuring. Something like this

```
const a = {b: 1, c: 2 , d: 3};
const forbiddenKeys = [ "b", "c"]; // pretend this is computed
const { ...forbiddenKeys, ...rest } = a; // gives "Uncaught SyntaxError: Rest element must be last element"
```

My plan was to use the `rest` variable after these operations to get the rest of the object that is not contained in `forbiddenKeys`. Is there a way to do this so that it works like the "Rest in object destructuring" section here? https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Destructuring_assignment#Computed_object_property_names_and_destructuring

Comment: Do you have a fixed amount of computed property names or are there always two of them?

Comment: You really should just copy them manually: `const rest = {}; for (const p in a) if (!forbiddenKeys.includes(p)) rest[p] = a[p];`

Comment: @Bergi it is a dynamic amount, not always two. Yes, I figured out a way to do it without destructuring